Bathroom Door Handle/Latch is Broken
The handle was not working properly and wouldn't activate the latch. Handle seemed to be acting as though it was locked when it wasn't. I took the plate off the latch and found that a piece of it was broken:


The handles move the latch and that broken piece around--they seem to be all connected. However I can't figure out how to get at the handles or how they're connected to the door. There are round plates that sit tight against the door have no screws visible to get at:


Seems like if I can get in behind those round plates I can see more but they don't seem to twist or snap off. I can get a pry tool in between the door and the plate, but it doesn't seem to budge. If I put any more pressure I'm afraid I'm going to damage the door.
Anyone familiar with these handles and this setup? The only hole there is to get at the lock from the outside, it does nothing to get the plate off so I can see the handle/lock/latch mechanism or how it's connected to the door. Any help/suggestions are hugely appreciated.

Not sure I follow completely. It seems that now that you've removed the broken part that the handle makes the latch retract properly. If that's the case, simply replace the broken piece with the not broken one (from the 2nd picture) and be done with it. What else is going on here?

I second just replacing the broken piece.  As for the door knobs/handles, there should be a hidden on the bottom, a screw, a tiny slot or a tiny pinhole.  The slot/pinhole is there to push in.

I get the impression that you had both latch plates installed. You're only supposed to use one. Kits include both to accommodate multiple mortise shapes. That's probably not the cause of your problem, but FYI.

Chances are there are screws under the round plates.  To get at them, you have to take the handles off by releasing a latch.  To do that, there's usually a small hole or gap somewhere in the base of the handle where you can insert a long, thin object and push.

Sorry for the delayed follow up. Let me try to answer all these comments.
The broken piece doesn't seem be be a part of the mechanism. I'm not entirely sure what function it serves, but with it removed, the door/latch/lock issue is still not working. It seems like something is inside the mechanism that needs to be fixed or replaced. But I can't seem to get to it because everything is connected.
I would suspect that as someone mentioned I have to get behind the round plates. But I can't figure out how they come off. There's no place to insert anything as described.

"handles move the latch" seems to indicate that the internal mechanism is working as expected. Do the handles move the latch, but it doesn't retract fully so the door won't open? If you need to remove the lock from the door, odds are good that there's a small hole in the bottom of the round ring through which you can access some sort of set screw that holds it in place. Once you've loosened that, you can slide the ring off and see how the rest of it is attached.
